# Unable to insert data into database properly using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, serialization, objectoutputstream

I started using the Hibernate recently. I am facing the below problem

Description: For the object customer, when I try to insert the data into database using hibernate saveOrUpdate it is deleting all the entries in the customer table and inserting only the new row with the new data. I am unable to figure out what is causing the problem. If try to insert another data same time by adding new Customer object (namely customer1) with different unique CODE after session.saveOrUpdate(customer), I am getting identifier already exists exception.

Definition of the table in database is as below

```
create table customer(
    code varchar(100) not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    address varchar(1000) not null,
    phone1 varchar(100) not null,
    phone2 varchar(100),
    credit_limit double default 0,
    current_credit double default 0,
    primary key ( code )
);
```

Java object defined is as below

---

```
package com.jwt.hibernate.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Customer implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2590997804699225005L;

    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone1;
    private String phone2;
    private Double creditLimit;
    private Double currentCredit;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getPhone1() {
        return phone1;
    }
    public void setPhone1(String phone1) {
        this.phone1 = phone1;
    }
    public String getPhone2() {
        return phone2;
    }
    public void setPhone2(String phone2) {
        this.phone2 = phone2;
    }
    public Double getCreditLimit() {
        return creditLimit;
    }
    public void setCreditLimit(Double creditLimit) {
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }
    public Double getCurrentCredit() {
        return currentCredit;
    }
    public void setCurrentCredit(Double currentCredit) {
        this.currentCredit = currentCredit;
    }
}
```

---

Class that is performing the hibernate action is as below

---

```
package com.jwt.hibernate.dao;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.jwt.hibernate.bean.Customer;

public class CustomerDAO {
    public boolean save(Customer customer){

        try{
        // 1. configuring hibernate
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        // 2. create sessionfactory
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        // 3. Get Session object
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        // 4. Starting Transaction
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        finally{

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Hibernate config xml is as below

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.jwt.hibernate.bean.Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
        <id column="CODE" name="code" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="NAME" name="name" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="ADDRESS" name="address" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="PHONE1" name="phone1" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="PHONE2" name="phone2" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="CREDIT_LIMIT" name="creditLimit" type="java.lang.Double" />
        <property column="CURRENT_LIMIT" name="currentCredit" type="java.lang.Double" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

Servlet that is handling the request is as below

---

```
package com.jwt.hibernate.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.jwt.hibernate.bean.Customer;
import com.jwt.hibernate.dao.CustomerDAO;


public class CustomerControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        try {
            Object object = (Object) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            String action = request.getParameter("action");
            if(action!= null && action.equals("save")){
                save(object, response);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void save(Object object, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

        Customer customer = (Customer) object;
        try {
            CustomerDAO customerDAO = new CustomerDAO();
            customerDAO.save(customer);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(customer);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {    
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Client side code that is sending the object to save to database is as below

---

```
public static Object save(Object object,int objectType)
    {
        URL url;
        if(objectType == TYPE_CUSTOMER) {
            Customer customer = (Customer) object;

            try {
                url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/CrossoverServer/Customer?action=save");
                urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlCon.setDoOutput(true); // to be able to write.
                urlCon.setDoInput(true); // to be able to read.

                out = new ObjectOutputStream(urlCon.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject(customer);
                out.close();

                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());
                customer = (Customer) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
                return customer;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch ( ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

---

The way customer object created is as below

---

```
public Object guiToObject() 
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCode(txtCode.getText());
        customer.setName(txtName.getText());
        customer.setAddress(txtAddress.getText());
        customer.setPhone1(txtPhone1.getText());
        customer.setPhone2(txtPhone2.getText());
        customer.setCreditLimit((Double) Double.parseDouble(txtCreditLimit.getText()));
        if(txtCurrentCredit.getText() != null && !txtCurrentCredit.getText().trim().isEmpty())
            customer.setCurrentCredit((Double) Double.parseDouble(txtCurrentCredit.getText().trim()));
        else
            customer.setCurrentCredit(0.0);
        return customer;
    }
```

---

Can some one please help me what is going wrong with the above approach of inserting new rows into customer table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason could be your code recreating the tables, and adding record afterwords.

Have you tried debugging and looking at the database side to see what is happening before insert?

One side note; your finally block is blank. You should have your session closing and similar stuff coded inside finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for he quick response.

I figured out the reason.

Changing the below property in hibernate.cfg.xml from "create" to "validate" resolved the problem.

validate

Thanks.